# getChildAt return a View that is null

Tags: android

I try to animate a single item in my `ListView`, I've figured out that this is kinda hard. But, after some googling I came up with some codesnippets that I combined, but when I try to call my `ListView`'s `getChildAt` in order to return the View, this returns null.

```
public void animateSingleItemInListView() {
        final Animation animBounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bounce);
        int totalItemsInListView = lastCases.getCount();
        int wantedPosition = 1; // Whatever position you're looking for
        int firstPosition = lastCases.getFirstVisiblePosition() - lastCases.getHeaderViewsCount(); // This is the same as child #0
        int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;
        // Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild will now be 2
        // So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
        int childs = lastCases.getChildCount();
        if (wantedChild < 0) {
          Log.w("UPDATEUI", "Unable to get view for desired position, because it's not being displayed on screen.");
          return;
        }
        // Could also check if wantedPosition is between listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() and listView.getLastVisiblePosition() instead.
        View wantedView = lastCases.getChildAt(firstPosition);
        wantedView.setAnimation(animBounce);
    }
```

From the code:

The `totalItemsInListView` returns 10, which is correct number of rows in my `ListView`. The integer `firstPosition` is of course 0, but the `getChildAt()` method only returns null. How come? How can I get the first `View` from my `ListView`?

Answer (score -1):

try to use

```
lastCases.getItemAtPosition(firstPosition)
```

Comment: This will only return an `object` to me, I want a View.

Comment: View wantedView = (View) lastCases.getChildAt(firstPosition);

Comment: Nope the `wantedView` is still `null`.

Comment: View wantedView = (View) lastCases.getItemAtPosition(firstPosition)

Comment: This will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Are you sure you need to get the element at position "firstPosition", but not in position "wantedChild"?

Comment: No, am not sure. But even if I try a single integer like 2 the view is still null.. Can see why, and yes my ListView does exist and is populated.